# How to do mass custom object attribute changes?

Tags: custom-object

I am trying to add object description fields but wanted to see if there was a way to export Object field attributes then import them back in using a csv?

Comment: Are you talking about the description attributes on fields on Sobjects? If so, I have no idea how to do this - but I'd really like to find out ...

Comment: Yes , Description Attributes. I am poking around with @viasur advice but have yet to be able to pull the column and attributes side by side.. For example have a csv column with object fieldA and the next column its atribute "description" or say "help text" .. fill those out and import them back in

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to run a report with the fields you want to modify, don't forget to add the Id field, from the object you intend to use. After running your report you can easily export that report to excel or csv. Make the modification and get them back to your system with DataLoader.

Comment: I pulled the fields I need to modify but am unable to add the description field attribute alongside them. I might try to a different Report format? (matrix,? .. Basically I would like to have 2 columns .. one would be the field name (e.g Booking) and the other column "description"

Comment: Hello Hamid. Sorry I didn't fully understood your question. As far as I know this is something that is not possible at this moment in Salesforce. Even if you use the Describe calls in APEX I'm affray you are not going to access the description field. I believe there is a way, I have never tried it, but it looks like it is extremely difficult because it requires retrieve calls.

You can check this information: 

http://andyinthecloud.com/2013/10/27/introduction-to-calling-the-metadata-api-from-apex/